# Ember include external JS via external HTTP server

Tags: ember.js

I would like to include this library ([Bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/getting-started.html)) . It does have a an npm package, but I would like to include it via its CDN (public url).

What is the right way to include external javascript (and css) files which reside on publicly accessible servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want it in your `vendor.js` file, the only way I know is to import it in your `index.html`.
Just place it in your `index.html` with a script tag.

By the way, you can create an addon, that only has an `index.js` that implements the `content-for` hook. This hook can insert the `script` tag for you. e.g:

```
contentFor:function(type, config){
  if(type==='head'){ //or body, choose the appropriate one for you
    return "<script src='...'></script>"
  }
}
```

Comment: hmmmm, thanks a lot. Ya, I guess this is the only way, I can go ahead. 
Wish there will be support for public uri in the future - if not hopefully there is a good reason not to have it. :)

Comment: BTW - I was trying not to tamper with the index.html file. Do you think it is wise (safe enough) to make changes to it?

Comment: I haven't read anything about "modifing `index.html` is bad" or vice versa. But actually I have a motivation to not to tamper `index.js` too. If I were you, I would prefer the second choice (writting an addon).

Comment: Thanks @ykaragol !